# c++ loop through a class private unique_ptr array from non-friend external utility function without using c-style for loop

Tags: c++

I've got a class with:

```
class vector_class {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> my_vector;
    int size_;

public:
    auto at(int) const -> int; // returns value at subscript
    auto at(int) -> int&;
    auto size() -> int; // returns vector size
}
```

I've been asked to construct an external function that takes 2 of these objects and returns the inner_product. Problem is that I have the following restrictions:

1. Can't add any public functions.
2. Shouldn't use friendship
3. Shouldn't use c-style for loops (i.e. should use algorithms).
4. Can't use any stl containers.

I can't use for_each because I don't have an iterator (since the vector is private non-friend).
I can't do for (i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) ... (since no basic for loop).

I guess I could write a custom iterator class but this is a lot of work and wondering if I've missed an easier solution... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators were designed to emulate much of the behavior of pointers, so much that all pointers can be used as iterators.

So if you have an array, and the number of elements in the array, you can use a pointer to the first element of the array as the `begin` iterator. And a pointer to one element beyond the last element (i.e. `begin + size`) as the `end` iterator. Then you can use these "iterators" with any normal standard function expecting an iterator pair.

For your specific case, `&my_vector[0]` as begin, and `&my_vector[size_]` as end.

Now, due to the limitations and requirements of your exercise, the simplest solution is probably to get these pointers through the public `at()` function. Or if the class has an overloaded `operator[]` you can use that instead:

```
inner_product(&i[0], &i[i.size()], &j[0]);
```

---

Because there are two overloads of the `at` function (and probably of the `[]` operator if it exists) we might need to specifically ask for the overload that returns a reference, if the compiler doesn't select the correct overloads to begin with.

This can be done by defining our own temporary reference variables:

```
auto const& first_begin  = i[0];
auto const& first_end    = i[i.size()];
auto const& second_begin = j[0];

auto result = inner_product(&first_begin, &first_end, &second_begin, 0);
```

Or, since it seems that the `at` function have a proper reference-returning overload, you can use that instead of `[]`:

```
auto result = inner_product(&i.at(0), &i.at(i.size()), &j.at(0), 0);
```

Comment: It's not a member function. It's external to the class and not a friend so it can't access the private array directly.

Comment: @JamesNancy95 Updated answer with a possible workaround

Comment: That's what I was just trying but now am getting "Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type int".

Comment: @JamesNancy95 That seems to be because the compiler selects the non-reference overload, and you must force that. Added example on how to force use of the reference-returning functions. However, that shouldn't be needed if the class have declared the correct functions. Perhaps it doesn't have an `operator[]` overload that returns a reference? You can also replace the use of the `[]` operator with `at()`.